# Saving Enum with description and key - MySQL and Java

Tags: java, spring

I have an enum as follows

```
public enum OrderStatusEnum {
    ACTIVE("A","Active Order"),
    AWAITING("I","Awaiting Order")
}
```

I want to save ACTIVE, AWAITING in the database. Also retrieve the same on query

I'm facing exception when entity is getting set as enum and saved via JdbcTemplate. Data Truncate exception

Questions

1. Do I need to save ACTIVE/AWAITING in the database or Active Order/Awaiting Order ?
2. How to save the enum value using native SQL queries using JdbcTemplate

We are using `MapSqlParameterSource`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can store 'ACTIVE/AWAITING' and use `valueOf` method of enum.
*Pros:*

1. no need to write additional code for mapping method - use standard
   `enum`'s `valueOf`.
2. values in database are more human-readable
3. there is enforcement on all enum's constants names to be unique, so this type of bug is eliminated

*Cons:*

1. potentially more space to store these values in database
2. renaming of enum's constants will lead to need to update database records

For example:

Inserting data into table:

```
jdbcTemplate.update(
    "INSERT INTO orders (id, order_status, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
    new Object[] {
        order.getId(),
        order.getStatus().toString(),
        order.getDescription()
    }
);
```

Loading data:

```
public List<Order> findAllOrders() 
{
    return jdbcTemplate.query(
        "SELECT * FROM orders",
        new String[]{},
        (rs, rowNum) -> new Order(rs.getInt("id"), OrderStatus.valueOf(rs.getString("order_status")), rs.getString("description"))
    );
}
```

The neat thing here is that you do not need to write `valueOf` method, it's present in any enum, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-

2) you can use `shortName` (for example, "A"), but than you'll need to iterate through all enums to find correct enum.
*Pros:*

1. potentially less space to store these values in database

*Cons:*

1. need to write additional code for mapping method
2. values in database are far less human-readable
3. there is possibility to add 2 enum constants with same short name, which will lead to data corruption

For example:

For saving use `order.getStatus().getShortName()`
For Loading use: `getStatus(rs.getString("order_status"))`:

```
private OrderStatus getStatus(String shortName)
{
    switch(shortName)
    {
        case "A":
            return OrderStatus.ACTIVE;
        case "I":
            return OrderStatus.AWAITING;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find order status for short name: " + shortName);
    }
}
```

**Update**: `OrderStatus` enum declaration:

```
public enum OrderStatus
{
    ACTIVE("A","Active Order"),
    AWAITING("I","Awaiting Order");

    private String shortName;
    private String description;

    private OrderStatus(String shortName, String description)
    {
        this.shortName = shortName;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getShortName()
    {
        return shortName;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }   
}
```

**Update 2**: mapping between OrderStatus and it's desired database representation should be made by you explicitely. If you would like to use `shortName` for mapping, you should express it somehow in code, otherwise how it will know how you would like to map it? You can use another way of mapping, which means that different approaches exist. For example, there is approach where you can save `OrderStatus.ordinal()`, and then transform it using `OrderStatus.values()[rs.getInt("order_status")]`. In this case you might use less space for storing value depending on your DBMS, but in case if you'll add more enum constants the existing constants might obtain different values for `OrderStatus.SOME_ENUM_CONSTANT.ordinal()`, which leads to data corruption or need to update old records in database and then start new version of the application, that's why I didn't include this option into list of mapping options.

Comment: Can u please share the code of toString() and valueOf(). As i am getting Data Truncation error if i pass addValue("orderStatus", OrderStatusEnum.AWAITING). valueOf throws error. Code snippet for enum defintion would be useful

Comment: It throws error as Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.mkyong.model.OrderStatusEnum.Awaiting when valueOf is being called.

Comment: for saving you said to use short_name where in the above insert sql you have mentioned "order.getStatus().toString()," can u please share the code for shortName, toString() and valueOf() method so it would be clear.

Comment: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/84770-insert-with-enum-s-on-both-ends

Comment: You can fix data truncation error by: 1) changing field max length for enum in yoor database, i.e. status varchar(20); 2) using 2nd approach: shortName. valueOf expects "ACTIVE" or "AWAITING", otherwise it will throw error. toString() is standard enum's method. You can check output from this code: `System.out.println("toString: " + OrderStatus.ACTIVE.toString());` `OrderStatus status = OrderStatus.valueOf("ACTIVE");` `System.out.println("Short name: " + status.getShortName());`

Comment: What is the standard approach ?

Comment: I would say that the way you map enum to database field depends on your desire. In any way you should tell code how to map. I have seen different approaches to map, and listed them in my answer, and all of them are used. When you are using JdbcTemplate you do a lot of things manually. In JPA you have more options.

Comment: Thanks and we can close this as answered

Comment: You are welcome. To mark my answer as answered you can accept it. More details are in https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers